Building and Publishing Expo Managed Workflow App Without Expo EAS
I'm currently working on a project with Expo's managed workflow. I want to build and publish the app by myself without using Expo EAS (I know I can use prebuild, but it still requires login). I'm aware I can build and publish using the regular Xcode or Android Studio workflows, but the issue is that I would need to set up android/app/build.gradle, as stated in the docs at React Native Docs. The problem is, the next time I run expo prebuild command, it will override these settings.
What are the possible solutions?

There is only one option to create android/ios folder and generate build. When you want to create EAS build then you should delete native ios and android folder.

as i thought, i wanted to use prebuild only for the cicd server but the problem is with setup local native files ios/android prebuild delete them, I can make a plugin that write android/app/build.gradle but I think it is a bad approach
